# How to select records but exclude if one type is outside a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have multiple invStatus values (1-10) and want to exclude only one status type (1) BUT only those of that type that are a older than X number of days.  So all records will show but NOT those who's invStatus = 1 and is older than X days. invStatus = 1 and younger than X days will be included in the recordset.

Do I select all records generically, then in a subquery filter those of status = 1 that are older than X days?

The query below uses NOT IN in an attempt to select those records to exclude but it is not working and also seems to be inefficient as it takes a couple seconds to execute.

```
SELECT 
    tblinventory.invId, 
    tblinventory.invTitle, 
    tblinventory.invStatus, 
    tblhouseinfo.Address, 
    tblhouseinfo.City, 
    tblhouseinfo.`State`, 
    tblhouseinfo.Zip, 
    tblhouseinfo.Update_date, 
    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AS dateEx 
FROM 
    tblinventory 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblhouseinfo ON tblinventory.invId = tblhouseinfo.addInfoID 
WHERE 
    invReleased = 0 
    AND invStatus NOT IN (SELECT invId from tblhouseinfo WHERE invStatus = 1 
AND tblhouseinfo.Update_date < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )

ORDER BY 
    `tblhouseinfo`.`Update_date` DESC
```

I could filter the results with PHP on the page level but this also seems less than efficient and would prefer to perform this task using the best practices.

UPDATE:
There are a total of 155 rows. 
All tblhouseinfo.Update_date (timestamp) values are "2017-09-06 10:53:17" (Aug 9th)  accept three I changed for testing to "2017-07-06 10:53:17
" (July 6th)

Utilizing the suggestion for :

```
AND NOT (invStatus = 1 AND tblhouseinfo.Update_date > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )
```

60 records are excluded not the expected 3.

"2017-08-28" is the current result from CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY which should be within the 10 day range to select "2017-09-06 10:53:17" and only exclude the three records that are "2017-07-06 10:53:17"

FINAL WORKING SOLUTION/Query:

```
 SELECT 
    tblinventory.invId, 
    tblinventory.invTitle, 
    tblinventory.invStatus, 
    tblhouseinfo.Address, 
    tblhouseinfo.City, 
    tblhouseinfo.`State`, 
    tblhouseinfo.Zip, 
    tblhouseinfo.Update_date, 
    CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AS dateEx 
FROM 
    tblinventory 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblhouseinfo ON tblinventory.invId = tblhouseinfo.addInfoID 
WHERE 
    invReleased = 0 
    AND NOT (invStatus = 1 AND tblhouseinfo.Update_date < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )
ORDER BY 
    `tblhouseinfo`.`Update_date` DESC
```

Comment: It's hard to provide accurate advice without knowing the structure of your tables. It's generally better to perform the operation in a query vs having to iterate over the rows in something like PHP. Your other option for the query is to use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
        tblinventory.invId, 
        tblinventory.invTitle, 
        tblinventory.invStatus, 
        tblhouseinfo.Address, 
        tblhouseinfo.City, 
        tblhouseinfo.`State`, 
        tblhouseinfo.Zip, 
        tblhouseinfo.Update_date, 
        CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AS dateEx 
    FROM 
        tblinventory 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblhouseinfo ON tblinventory.invId = tblhouseinfo.addInfoID 
    WHERE 
        invReleased = 0 
        AND NOT (invStatus = 1 AND tblhouseinfo.Update_date < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY )
    ORDER BY 
        `tblhouseinfo`.`Update_date` DESC
```

Comment: your suggestion removed 60 records from the query results as noted in my update to the question. Thanks but there must be more to this than I currently understand.

Comment: SOLUTION:
AND NOT (invStatus = 1 AND tblhouseinfo.Update_date < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)

Needed to reverse from Greater Than to Less Than

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select invID from the other table if you know you never want the ID #1 (invStatus 1). But you can also throw in an AND statement for the # of days.

I always use timestamps (in UNIX) for recording data entry / modification.

```
AND (timestamp >= beginTimestamp AND timeStamp <= endTimestamp)
```